# Get "Day" of Selected Date in ngb-datepicker (ng Bootstrap) in Angular Application

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

**Demo:**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bife8z-px13fl?file=app%2Fdatepicker-basic.html

I have added Day(Sunday) as static text, i want this to be changed according to date selection form calendar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764233/ngb-datepickerng-bootstrap-display-day-with-date-as-dd-mmm-yy-example-output (it's your old question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the calendar to get the day of the week and have a Dictionary which stores the Day names.

```
weekDays = {
  1: 'Monday',
  2: 'Tuesday',
  3: 'Wednesday',
  4: 'Thursday',
  5: 'Friday',
  6: 'Satarday',
  7: 'Sunday'
}

Selected Date is: <b>{{weekDays[calendar.getWeekday(model)]}}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bife8z-bftzuu?file=app%2Fdatepicker-basic.html

Infact you can have a variable for day which gets set in the setter of the `model` variable.

```
  selectedDay: string = '';
  set model(val) {
    this._model = val;
    this.selectedDay = this.weekDays[this.calendar.getWeekday(this.model)]
  }

  get model() {
    return this._model;
  }

 Selected Date is: <b>{{selectedDay}}</b> <br>
```

Comment: How to show month full name instead of Number (Example: "January","February"..."December").  

I want date format is Friday, 12-December-2018.

Comment: @Ezhil-UIDeveloper: Then you can probably use the same logic of keeping the month names in a javascript object and mapping the names with `allMonths[model.month]`

Comment: I tried as u mentioned its's working. thanks. 
Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bife8z-xnb8yq

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

component html

```
Selected Date is: <b>{{getDay(model)}}</b>
```

component ts

```
  getDay(model){
    let date = new Date(Date.UTC(model.year, model.month - 1, model.day, 0, 0, 0))
    let days = new Array( "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",  "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" );
    let day = days[date.getDay() - 1]
    return day
  }
```

Comment: NOT use new Date(model.year,model.month-1,model.day). If you live in GTM+1 you get a day less, use **new Date(Date.UTC(date.year, date.month - 1, date.day, 0, 0, 0))**, or use new Date(model.year,model.month-1,model.day **,12** )

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for the catch, added your fix.